Textbooks recommendations for wireless communication
I would like a recommendation for two textbooks:

General wireless communication. Both in terms of architecture, HW components, etc., and signal processing point of view.
Introduction to WiFi (IEEE802.11)

I know there are many books, but I’m looking for recommendations of what books are most effective.
In response to a comment, I’m well versed in probability and basics dog signal processing. I’m looking more for specifics of architecture of transmitters and receivers, soecific algorithms used, as well as the WiFi spec.

This is a bit broad. What's the background you're coming from? If you're in an electrical engineering or a technical computer science degree program where there's a digital communications lecture, I'd recommend you write an email to the lecturer and ask for a textbook recommendation – it's easiest when the literature uses the same terminology as the lectures you hear. Otherwise, giving us a bit of a background (to let us estimate how much math basics, how much signal theory basics, probability basics… you need) and where you want to be after reading the two books would very much help!

@MarcusMüller Thanks Marcus. I’m not a student so a lecturer is irrelevant:) I’m well versed in probability, and signal processing basics. I’m looking more for specifics regarding communication systems, and the WiFi standard. I have an MSc in physics and phd and electrical engineering even though I never took EE as an undergrad so I’m not really an electrical engineer.

Nice! With a physics background and probability theory in your personal toolbox, I'd say a good starter textbook is Amos Lapidoth's A Foundation in Digital Communications is probably a good choice; it's nice and systematic. And, the author makes it available for free.
But that doesn't go into OFDM, so you'd want to maybe start with it only, to understand the basics of single-carrier techniques, constellations and inter-symbol interference quickly, and with some mathematical rigor, and then switch over to a copy of Proakis & Salehi's Digital Communications fifth edition, which does OFDM nicely! (You can also directly start with "the Proakis", but it's a rather thick book and with your background, you might just be able to just make quick progress;  and I personally found Lapidoth's style just entertaining, but I've got friends who say I'm strange for exactly that reason.) But it's an expensive book. Maybe borrow it from a library first: It's definitely something most technical libraries have. However, Tse & Viswanath (see next paragraph) do cover OFDM as well, and it might be good enough (or even better for your taste!).
Now, to understand modern Wifi from a physical layer point of view, you'd probably want a bit of a background in the physics of the channel, especially the MIMO and multi-user access problems you'll encounter. I'd consider Tse & Viswanath's Fundamentals of Wireless Communication a good book for people who have gotten used to the basics of digital communications, and want to dive deeper into these aspects of communications systems. It also happens to be available for free from the authors.
Regarding specialist literature on Wifi itself: I'm not aware of any specific textbooks on that, but I'm sure some exist. However, having worked through a solid introduction to OFDM, I think you'll be fine with the standard itself. You might find Schmidl & Cox' classic paper on their synchronization method, Robust Frequency and Timing Synchronization for OFDM helpful to make sense of the preamble. It's a nice paper! I'd say, it also works as a good self-test: if you understand the theory part of it, your basics in OFDM and multipath channels are solid and you can dive right into the "higher layers", be it network aspects in OFDM, or power allocation, or MCS, or…

Thanks so much! Much appreciated!
